# Delete a single image from a foreach (Firebase Storage)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have a `forEach()` that shows a couple of images. I would like these to be deleted if needed. I fetch the src of the image and the path/file name of the image from Firestore to show with the image on my site (they are uploaded to storage and Firestore).

How do I identify a single image out of all of them and delete just that one?

Js Code

```js
const i = query(collection(db, "teamImages"));
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(i, (querySnapshot) => {
  const teams = document.querySelector('.teamimages');

  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const docData = doc.data();
    const article = teams.appendChild(document.createElement('article'));
    article.innerHTML = `
        <p class="path"></p>
        <img class="team-image">
    `;
    article.children[0].textContent = docData.path;
    article.children[1].src = docData.url;

    console.log("Current data: ", docData);
  });


  document.getElementById("team-image").addEventListener("click", function deleteImage() {

const filename = document.getElementById("path").innerHTML;

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this image')) {

        const imageDeleteRef = ref(storage, filename);

  // Delete the file
            deleteObject(imageDeleteRef).then(() => {

  // File deleted successfully & delete firestorm reference

           deleteDoc(doc(db, teamImage, filename));


            }).catch((error) => {
  // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            });

    } else {
      // Do nothing!
      console.log('Image not deleted');

    };

  });
});
```

The images are in an article section (createElement).

I've had some undefined and null errors when I tried to put in any Firebase delete code.

I'm just not sure how I can define the image filename to use as the reference to delete the file.

Comment: Could you share the full code which also includes the function deleteImage() ?

Comment: yeah I'll add it, but was just the standard Firebase code. It worked when I placed it inside the brackets of the forEach() but that message appeared three times.

Comment: I've posted an answer below. Did it resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

The issue looks to be related to how you are setting and getting data for the storage.

You are trying the build the ref using

```
'const imageDeleteRef = ref(storage, filename);'
```

From the snippet is not clear what is storage, you could print out the

 -storage

-filename

to console to verify that you are fetching proper element.

Here you are setting the data

```
 article.innerHTML = `
        <p class="path"></p>
        <img class="team-image">
    `;
    article.children[0].textContent = docData.path;
    article.children[1].src = docData.url;
```

This will produce

```
<p class="path">docData.path</p>
<img class="team-image" src="{docData.url}">
```

Then you are trying to get

```
"const filename = document.getElementById("path").innerHTML;"
```

You are using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById where the name is set under class named "path"  and possibly you should use

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

const filename = document.getElementsByClassName("path"),innerHTML;

Or you could change the class to id

from

```
 article.innerHTML = `
        <p class="path"></p>
        <img class="team-image">
    `;
```

to

```
 article.innerHTML = `
        <p id="path"></p>
        <img id="team-image">
    `;
```